# How to repeat Crystal Report Header on each page

Tags: crystal-reports

[image]I am using Cross Tab report. i have to print heading on each page. but i know report header repeat only once in a report. any possibility to print each page?

Comment: Also i cannot use cross tab report in page header or footer.

Comment: Use cross tab in sub report and then place the sub report in report header...in sub report place in group but not in report header

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on that group header -> `change group` and check marked checkbox (in picture below).

[image]

That should do it.

**EDIT :** you are right, `report header` and `report footer` show only once per report, but for your problem you can use `page header` and `page footer` which repeat on each page.

Comment: But its working only group header data. that's not my problem. i want show dynamic columns so i added one cross tab report in Report Header.

Comment: I advise that you put cross tab in page footer and check  [this](http://scn.sap.com/thread/1988860)  for more help