# Display report header in every page of cross tab in Crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to display report header in every page of my cross tab report in Crystal Reports 13. Currently the header only appears on the first page. How can I fix this problem? Kindly suggest me.

Check bellow screen shot

*Page 1:*

[image: 1st page(where report header display)]

*Page 2:*

[image: 2nd page where report header disappear]

*Design View:*

Comment: In the report header section, check "conserv unit" and don't check "Background in the following sections"

Comment: Can you kindly explain me where i will check "conserv unit"

Comment: Right click on the report header section then click expert section

Comment: Right click on the report header and went to "section expert" but don't find anything like "conserv unit" I got three tab "Common,Paging and Color". In Common Tab there are six option 1.Hide 2. Print a bottom page. 3.Supress. 4.Keep Together 5.Supress Blank Section. 6.Underlay following Section. For your kind information I mentioned I am using Crystal report 13.0.7

Comment: Check keep together , and don't check underlay following section

Comment: If you want those to display on every page, it seems to me you want to use the *Page* Header instead of the Report Header.

Comment: Dear Furito, Do you know Cross tab report can't place in page header.Cross tab only take place in Report Header and Group Header(But Group by is not needed for my report).if i place report header inside of page header then report header display middle of detail data .If you have any other idea you can share Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the selected fields in report header and go to `format` and check option `Repeat on Horizontal Pages` so that it applies for every page

Comment: I did according to your mention process but not working.

Comment: It should work... tested solution.. can you show what have you done?

Comment: Dear Siva, I added another screen shot for your understanding please check and kindly explain me if i did wrong.

Comment: ok your problem is... insert one more section Report header2 and place corss tab in that section and rest all fields in Report Header 1 and set the property for all fields of report header 1 as suggested

Comment: Thanks Siva now Report Header display horizontally.but My concern is not to display report Header Horizontally.My concern is when I go to next page Report Header will display there I mean every Page.But till now its only display on first page,in 2nd page report header disappear. For your kind information,If i place report header in group header then it display each page but group by is not needed for my report. Is there any formula needed?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do following things:

1. right-clicking on the row header
2. select Row options
3. select Repeat Labels on Page break

Crystal Reports lets you designate report objects that don't expand horizontally, such as text objects, field objects, OLE objects, charts, maps, lines, boxes, and so on, to be repeated on each additional horizontal page that a Cross-Tab creates.

Check [this](http://scn.sap.com/thread/1988860) for help.

Also, similar question `How to repeat Crystal Report Header on each page` answered by me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37614766/5139222). If you still after this links don't get solution, feel free to ask so we go into details of your cross-tab etc...

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved the problem to display header for cross tab report in each page.

1.Create a formula using bellow code

WhileReadingRecords;

""

2.Create a Group Field using that formula field (which is empty group)

3.Crete Cross Tab Report inside of group header section.

4.Finally place my report header inside of page header section.

Now its working according to my demand and display report header every page

Thanks all of you

Check bellow screen shot
[image: Page-1]

[image: Page-2]

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of headers in Crystal Reports. There are Report Headers (which you're currently using) and there are **Page Headers** (which are what you *want* to use in this case.)

- A Report Header will only display once - on the first page.
- A Page Header will appear on *every* page. (Unless you
  specifically tell it *not* to.)

Move the circled fields into a Page Header and suppress the old Report Header you were using before. If all goes well, you'll see the circled field on every page going forward.

Answer (score 0):

One other possible approach would be to insert a separate section above each crosstab that will contain your repeating Page Header. (Section Expert -> Insert) or (Right click Section -> Insert Section Below)

Then for the aforementioned inserted section, force a page break before. (Section Expert -> New Page Before)

Repeat this step for each Report Header section that contains a crosstab. The downside is that you will have many pages depending on the number of crosstabs in your report. Hope it helps.